# Is there a tree structure with multiple root nodes, if so, what is it called?

Tags: data-structures, tree, nodes

A classical tree has one root node. Example:
[image]

Is there a tree with multiple initial roots like in the picture?:
[image]

Comment: If you separated the trees (no edges between the roots) it would be called a *forest*.

Comment: That second example is confusing: is this a directed graph or not? The edges between the "roots" are not directed, and the other edges are?

Comment: Such structure exists, you draw it. As @JoeSewell said this structure is called a forest. There a theorem that any forest is topologically equivalent to binary tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Joe Sewell noted in the comments, a collection of independent trees is called a *forest*. This term applies both to collections of directed rooted trees like the one you showed above, plus collections of undirected, unrooted trees as well.

Many data structures and algorithms make use of forests. The binomial and Fibonacci heap data structures store their items in a collection of smaller independent trees. Link/cut trees, which are used in some maximum flow algorithms, work with independent collections of trees as well.